Error com.android.aaptcompiler.ParsedResource@25e26fca
I am trying to make an Android App for my Bachelor Degree, I study Economical Information, and I just can't find a solution to solve the problem, when I am trying to compilate what I write in the code of my future application.I would like to specify that, I don't have any errors in Android Manifest,activity_main.XML or MainActivity.kt. I chose to start this project with Android 7.0 build.
When I am trying to compilate my project, I receive this error:
Can not extract resource from com.android.aaptcompiler.ParsedResource@1f8cbee4.,Can not extract resource from com.android.aaptcompiler.ParsedResource@4ff160b4.,Can not extract resource from com.android.aaptcompiler.ParsedResource@5fe7f985. FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
``
`Execution failed for task':app:mergeDebugResources'.


A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.ResourceCompilerRunnable
Resource compilation failed (Failed to compile values resource file C:\Users\Antonia\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication2\app\build\intermediates\incremental\debug\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml.
Cause: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not extract resource from com.android.aaptcompiler.ParsedResource@1f8cbee4.,Can not extract resource from com.android.aaptcompiler.ParsedResource@4ff160b4.,
Can not extract resource from com.android.aaptcompiler.ParsedResource@5fe7f985.).`
I will put the code for resource file:

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <item name="fragment_container_view_tag" type="id"/>
    <item name="special_effects_controller_view_tag" type="id"/>
    <item name="visible_removing_fragment_view_tag" type="id"/>
    <declare-styleable name="Fragment">
        <attr name="android:name"/>
        <attr name="android:id"/>
        <attr name="android:tag"/>
    </declare-styleable>
    <declare-styleable name="FragmentContainerView">
        <attr name="android:name"/>
        <attr name="android:tag"/>
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>`

I really need your help, please, because it's my Bachelor Degree and I need to sent this application to my coordinator. I would really appreciate your help!
